# Highlighting an active class in an unordered list when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nav, smooth-scrolling

I am currently trying to implement smooth scrolling with a position indicator in my navigation menu. I want to be able to change the color or distinguish between the active part of the fixed nav bar when scrolling (i.e. when in the about section the about part of the navbar is highlighted). Does anyone have some advice? I don't want to use bootstrap or a plugin.

Here is the html for my nav bar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"> 
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="top-menu">
      <li id="home"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <li id="about"><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li id="contact"><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

SCSS:

```
nav{
    /* spacing */
    text-align: center;

    /*font*/
    font-size: 30px;

    /* alignment */
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 9999;
    border-radius: 0;
    position: fixed;

    /* dimensions */
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    border-width: 5px;

ul{
  margin-top:15px;
}

ul li{
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top:4px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a, ul li a.active{
  color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: .5s all ease-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s all ease-out;
  transition: .5s all ease-out;
  }
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    var pgurl = window.location.href.substr( window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    $(".navbar ul li a").each(function(){
       if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
          $(this).addClass("active");
    })
});
```

Comment: I believe [scrollspy](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp) is exactly what you are looking for

Comment: Are you familiar with a method of doing it without bootstrap?